# Как можно прокрутить экран приложения в Google Play до звезд?

Tags: android, google-play

Допустим приложение умеет открывать себя в Google Play. Как можно при открытии экрана сделать автоматическую прокрутку до звезд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Такой возможности не предусмотрено.

Comment: Я помню когда был "юзером" видел такое, вот хоть убейте, не помню что за приложение было

Comment: @Flippy, не могу ничего сказать. Думаю, эта фича настолько востребована, что, если б она существовала, то о ней бы все знали.